# save to homescreen is not working

Tags: 7.0-nougat, home-screen-shortcuts

Android Nougat 7.0 on Motox Pure 2015 -- rooted

I can't save shortcuts to home-screen anymore. None of the installed browsers save to home-screen. Google maps doesn't save to home-screen.

I just tried to save a directions shortcut from Google maps and it said that the shortcut was saved, but it is not.

Added edit:
Here is a log entry while saving the Google maps shortcut:

```
[10-06 09:18:46.584 1146:1179 W/BroadcastQueue]
Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.android.launcher3.InstallShortcutReceiver
```

I'm starting to think this has to do with one of my battery app background restricter apps.  I am testing that out now.

Comment: SOLVED: I allowed com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox to run in the background and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Looks like you have found the solution by yourself, and that's good! However, can you post it as an answer instead? Comment is not for providing the solution, and you can also mark the answer to indicate that the question has been solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I allowed com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox to run in the background and that fixed the problem.

In my case the app that was restricting was called `BackgroundRestrictor`.

I also have both the `RootBooster` and `Hibernation` apps running, and they didn't need any adjusting.